# Json and Ruby creating a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have a method that I can to push to a JSON call. The function looks like:

```
def  my_function(name, text , id_person, id_company)
end
```

What I want is to get:

```
{"my_function":{"name":"names_value","text":"text_value ","id_person":"id_person_value","id_company":"id_company_value"}
```

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Why can't you just return that as a hash and serialize it (or serialize it in the method)? It's not clear what you're asking for. And are you really asking for a string or JSON? What does "pushing to a json call" mean?

Comment: As @DaveNewton said, your question isn't clear. Please take the time to explain it better, and, even better yet, supply more code showing what you're attempting to do. Similar to using a picture, code is worth 10,000 words.

Comment: i am looking to make it into a string. that is in json format.

Comment: @user3830714 : Please explain with a use-case and an illustrated example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear, but let me try with few answer possibilities

First of all this is not a JSON format

```
{"my_function":{"name":"names_value","text":"text_value ","id_person":"id_person_value","id_company":"id_company_value"}
```

There should not be double quote (") before semicolon (:)

```
obj = { 
      my_function:
        { 
          name: "names_value", 
          text: "text_value",
          id_person: "id_person_value",
          id_company: "id_company_value"
        }
    }
```

If you want to get each of the data in that "JSON" format, you could do this

```
name = obj['my_function']['name'] #name_value

text = obj['my_function']['text'] #text_value
```

and so on...

But if you want to make a string data into JSON format, you could do this

```
def my_function(name_value, text_value, id_person_value, id_company_value)
    { 
      my_function:
          {
              name: name_value,
              text: text_value,
              id_person: id_person_value,
              id_company: id_company_value
          }
     }.to_json
end
```

I hope it's answering your question...